# Where in umbracoSettings.config should I place ResolveUrlsFromTextString?

Tags: c#, configuration, umbraco

I am trying to fix issues related to having Umbraco installed under a virtual directory (i.e., not under root, but under `http://example.com/dir/site1`).

According to some posts, this can be resolved by using:

```
<ResolveUrlsFromTextString>true</ResolveUrlsFromTextString
```

But none of these posts, and not even the documentation page on that setting, say where you can use it. The [documentation suggests under `notications`](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/), but that gives an error "unrecognized setting".

Any idea *where* this setting should be placed in `umbracoSettings.config`?

I'm using Umbraco version 7.3.0 assembly: 1.0.5750.18157.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work in both v4 and v6 sites while located under content, as in

```
<settings>
    <content>
        <ResolveUrlsFromTextString>true</ResolveUrlsFromTextString>
    </content>
</settings>
```

Comment: I've tried that too no avail. Perhaps I misunderstand what it should do, I'm trying to run umbraco under a virtual directory, under which I've added a webapp which in turn points to the root of umbraco. Or are there other settings I should apply?

Comment: Btw, the site runs, but templates in admin give a 404, I tried adding them again but to no avail.

Comment: What version are we talking here?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written that in my question (just updated it). Version 7.3.0.

Comment: Alright, don't know 100% about v7, but if the setting isn't there to begin with I suspect you might be outta luck...

Comment: For now I'm going to consider it a bug of Umbraco. I'll see if I can fix it, perhaps with a few simple rewrite rules on the server, or at source level. Since your answer answers the question of _where_ it ought to be placed, I'll accept it, thanks :)